# Backbone Javascript || Re-Using Collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm a newbie in backbone js.

I have a collection that i have used in some view. I want to re use the same collection in another view. how it would be possible through backbone js.
All collection data i'm getting from some service
For Ex; collectionA has some data used in viewA.
I want to use collectionA in viewB where viewB is a routed page altogether.
Currently what's happening is collectionA is only scoped to viewA.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How to re use backbone collection in another view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25791460/1059101 use dependency injection. Angular does have it but backbone seems does not have it. check the link.

Comment: but in my case collection is only scoped to that particular view. If i'm trying to call in some other view its giving null response. because in my first view i'm calling some RESTful service which will give the response and store it in the Collection. I want to use same collection data in some other view

Answer (score 0):

A good practice in your Backbone application is to have a global Event bus, that you can use to communicate with different parts of your application.

A good use of events allow you to keep your application decoupled.

If you have for example a global App object accessible from everywhere you could attach an Event bus to it like so :

```
// your global Application object
var App = { ... };

// setting up the event bus
App.eventBus = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

// in your viewA, on your collection fetched callback
...
onCollectionFetched(collection) {
    App.eventBus.trigger('collection:fetched', collection);
}

// in your viewB, setup a listener in your initialize, for example
...
initialize: function() {
    App.eventBus.on('collection:fetched', function(collection) {
        // do something
    });
}
```